How to extract values from multiple Monte Carlo simulations and compile these as series of values in R?
I am doing Monte Carlo simulation using a triangular distribution in R.
rtriangle(n = 10000, a = 9100, b = 13234, c = 11585)

In this example, I am doing 10,000 iterations where 'a' is the minimum value, 'b' is the maximum, and 'c' is the mean. These values represent construction costs for a single house. The outcome of this simulation will be a distribution of values resulting from the 10,000 iterations.
What I want to do:

How do I extract/get the 50th percentile value in the distribution?
How do I rerun the simulation for 924 times - because I want to get construction values for 924 different houses (all the parameters remaining the same).
The final output I want to achieve is a compiled 50th percentile values out of the 924 simulations. In simple words, there will be 924 different construction cost values (representing the 50th percentile values for each of the 924 simulation).


The third parameter for rtriangle is the mode, not the mean. Those are the same if it’s a symmetric triangle, but can be quite different for asymmetric triangles.

My question for you is why are you doing this with simulation? The 50th percentile is the median, and is quite easy to calculate directly for a triangle distribution. Is there some reason you want to do this with via sampling rather than getting the exact answer through some straightforward math?

The mean of a triangular distribution is (min + max + mode)/3, so the mode is 3*mean - (max + min). If you intended for the mean to be 11585, then the mode is 12421, and the triangle is definitely not symmetric. Please clarify what’s what with your parameterization

@pjs I'm simulating possible construction costs of houses incorporating (epistemic) uncertainties. The 11585 is an estimated average construction cost of a single house. What I'm doing is to simulate the likely values if I have 924 different houses (so that I won't use the same value of 11585 for all 924 which is so deterministic).

@pjs thanks for the clarification re: mean vs mode for triangular distribution (very helpful!). For context, the 11585 is the estimated construction cost. (In the values I provided in the example above, those are  based from a certain data about min/max construction values). What I might consider moving forward is using the estimated construction cost, then derive the min and max values by getting +/- 10%.

Write an auxiliary function sim and call it 924 times with replicate.
And there is no need to also pass a value for c, it defaults to the mean of a and b.
sim <- function(n, a, b, c = (a + b)/2) {
  triangle::rtriangle(n, a, b, c = c) |> median()
}

R <- 924L

set.seed(2024)
medians_vec <- replicate(R, sim(n = 10000, a = 9100, b = 13234, c = 11585)) |> c()
head(medians_vec)
#> [1] 11362.95 11338.21 11373.15 11370.72 11359.24 11364.01
hist(medians_vec, main = "Medians' Empirical Distribution", xlab = "Median")


Created on 2024-08-15 with reprex v2.1.0

Edit
To have quantiles other than 50%, add an argument to function sim. The default is probs = 0.50 and sim computes the medians. Below I pass another value, probs = 0.95.
sim <- function(n, a, b, c = (a + b)/2, probs = 0.50) {
  triangle::rtriangle(n, a, b, c = c) |> quantile(probs = probs)
}

R <- 924L

set.seed(2024)
quant_vec <- replicate(R, sim(n = 10000, a = 9100, b = 13234, c = 11585, probs = 0.95)) |> c()
head(quant_vec)
#>      95%      95%      95%      95%      95%      95% 
#> 12636.26 12658.73 12644.44 12674.34 12641.63 12657.45

Created on 2024-08-16 with reprex v2.1.0
A vector of probabilities can also be passed on to sim. This time, I transpose the result and then compute the column means.
p <- c(0.50, 0.95)
quant_mat <- replicate(R, sim(n = 10000, a = 9100, b = 13234, c = 11585, probs = p)) |> t()
head(quant_mat)
#>           50%      95%
#> [1,] 11365.52 12645.07
#> [2,] 11376.34 12657.41
#> [3,] 11340.95 12645.37
#> [4,] 11373.86 12669.05
#> [5,] 11367.29 12666.63
#> [6,] 11376.18 12658.65
colMeans(quant_mat)
#>      50%      95% 
#> 11366.75 12649.78

Created on 2024-08-16 with reprex v2.1.0

By assigning the midpoint as c you seem to be assuming that it’s a symmetric triangle distribution. The parameters provided by OP say otherwise, regardless of whether the provided value of c is the mean or the mode.

@pjs You are right, I mistook the function default value for c with the OP value. Thanks, corrected now.

@RuiBarradas thanks legend! In case I might look at 95th percentile instead of 50th percentile, I reckon I just need to substitute c = (a+b)/2 ?

@Arvin No, to have other quantiles add an argument to sim. See the edit.
